# What does "cd.." mean in powershell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line, cd

I already know what it does: **It simply goes one directory or folder backwards**.

But what's mysterious for me are those two dot.

```
cd.. #it has the same function as popd with the difference that it changes the 
     #current working directory
```

If someone tell me what is the philosophy of putting those two **Dots**, i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please read the Microsoft article about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). It explains everything you need to know about Windows file systems, absolute and relative paths, etc.

Comment: The comment after `cd..` is nonsense. `popd` changes also the current directory. `popd` changes the current directory to directory which was the current directory before execution of corresponding `pushd`.

Comment: The command line `cd..` is syntactically not correct. The correct command line would be `cd ..` with a space between the command `cd` (argument 0) and its first and only parameter `..` (argument 1).

Comment: @Mofi: `cd..` is syntactically correct in both `cmd.exe` and PowerShell, it's just that they _mean different things_: in `cmd.exe`, `cd..` is the same as `cd ..`; in PowerShell, `cd..` _as a whole_ is the (potential) name of a _command_ - and indeed there is such a command, created to keep `cmd.exe` users happy; see my  answer for details.

Comment: @mklement0 I recognized too late that I should have written: The command line `cd..` is syntactically not 100% correct although working. Yes, `cmd.exe` executes also `cd..` and ``cd..\`` and `cd..\OtherFolder` although there is no space between command `cd` and its parameter `..` or ``..\`` or `..\OtherFolder`because of an error exception handling. This error handling can be seen on using free Sysinternals (Microsoft) [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon).

Comment: @mklement0 `cmd.exe` searches first in current directory for a file with name `cd` on using `cd..` which is usually not found and therefore results in error result *NAME NOT FOUND*. Then `cmd.exe` reinterprets the command line and executes `cd ..`. The search for a file `cd` does not occur on using  `cd ..`. `cmd.exe` searches first for a file with name `cd.` in current directory on using ``cd..\`` with result *NAME NOT FOUND* before changing to parent directory which does not occur on using ``cd ..\`` with a space between command `cd` and parameter ``..\``.

Comment: @mklement0 And last but not least `cmd.exe` searches in current directory for `cd.\OtherFolder` on using `cd..\OtherFolder` with result *PATH NOT FOUND* before changing the current directory to peer directory `OtherFolder`. The error condition does not occur with using 100% correct `cd ..\OtherFolder`. The execution of `cd..` in a cmd window results in error message if the current directory contains a file with name `cd` while `cd ..` works fine. The creation of a directory/file with name `cd.` is usually prevented by Windows, but can be achieved with using ``\\?\`` to bypass that prevention.

Comment: @mklement0 Microsoft explains some of the auto-corrections usually done on not 100% correct entered file or directory arguments on documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file). I prefer telling beginners 100% correct syntax and not a syntax working in 99.999999999 % of all uses cases due to error handling and auto-correction. Other example: `for %I in (C:/Windows/*.exe) do @echo %I` with not correct `/` as directory separator versus `for %I in (C:\Windows\*.exe) do @echo %I` with ``\`` as directory separator.

Comment: I appreciate the additional information, @Mofi. So that means that `cd..` in PowerShell actually works more robustly, though something like `cd..\Foo` doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`..`** in filesystem paths represents a given path's ***parent* path**.

Without an explicit path preceding the `..`, the implied path is the *current [working] directory*, so the `..` therefore refers to the current directory's *parent directory*.

In short: **`cd` with an argument of `..` changes to the current directory's *parent* directory**, i.e., the directory one level above in the directory hierarchy.

**Shell-specific use of `..` with `cd`:**

- The **legacy command processor, `cmd.exe`** ("Command Prompt") - seemingly with the internal `cd` command specifically (see [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi)'s comments on the question) - **considers an `.` character to implicitly start the `cd` command's *argument***.

  - Therefore, separating the `cd` *command* from the `..` *argument* with *a space character*, as usual, isn't *necessary*; that is, **instead of `cd ..` you can type `cd..`**, which is a shortcut that users of `cmd.exe` have grown accustomed to over the years.
- **PowerShell** **allows `.` characters to be used in command names**, so submitting **`cd..` does *not* invoke the `cd` command (a built-in alias for the `Set-Location` cmdlet) with argument `..`** - instead, it looks for a command *literally named* `cd..`

  - **To accommodate `cmd.exe` users who are accustomed to the `cd..` shortcut, PowerShell comes with a *parameter-less function literally named `cd..`***, so that submitting `cd..` as a command in PowerShell effectively works the same as in `cmd.exe`.

    - However, note that **only `cd..` works, not also specifying additional components**; that is, **something like `cd..\Foo` (which works in `cmd.exe`) fails**.
  - `Get-Command cd.. | Format-List` shows information about this function, which reveals that it simply calls `Set-Location ..`, which is PowerShell's equivalent of `cmd.exe`'s `cd ..`

Answer (score 1):

These two dots mean "One upper level in the directory".

`cd` specifies to change the directory and `..` means "upper level". So, `cd..` means exactly what you stated in your question.

**Example:** let's say you are in the folder **C:\x\y**. If you type `cd..`, you'll  be on **C:\x**