# Unable to move forward using cd

Tags: powershell, directory, cd

I'm having a problem moving forward through a path with PowerShell.  I am able to move up the directory but not down.  Here's the situation:

I open PowerShell and type in the "pwd" command and it shows that I am currently in **PS C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14>**

I type the command "cd.." and now I move to **PS C:\Users>**

I then attempt to change directories by typing: "cd C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14" and I am unable to. Unfortunately, I can't post a picture yet due to lack of reputation.

I'm able to perform the change in CMD but not PowerShell.  Also, I don't know how to change the  User from "Robert Inspiron14" to just "Robert".  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change `cd C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14` to `cd 'C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14'`

Comment: Allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment (you should accept Mathias' answer).

Answer (score 2):

Before PowerShell can execute your `cd` command, it needs to *parse it*, and PowerShell's parser interprets your command like this:

```
cd  C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14
\/  \_____________/ \________/
Command Name  |            |
             argument 1    |
                         argument 2
```

In other words, `C:\Users\Robert` and `Inspiron14` are interpreted as *separate arguments*.

Neither argument is a path to a valid directory, so `cd` (or rather `Set-Location` for which `cd` is an alias) throws an error.

You can force PowerShell to recognize `C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14` as a single string argument by qualifying its boundaries using quotation marks (both `"` and `'` will work):

```
cd 'C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14'
```

You can read more about how PowerShell parses command expressions in the [`about_Parsing` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#argument-mode)

Comment: Amazing.  After you explained that I also realized I could use ` to denote the space as well.

Comment: That'd work as well - it _escapes_ the space - telling PowerShell's parser "don't treat this next one as you normally would"

Comment: Nicely done; quibble: while it is true that neither argument is a valid directory path, the reason that an error occurs is that `Set-Location` only accepts _one_ argument _positionally_, and the resulting syntax error _preempts_ any check for whether `C:\Users\Robert` exists.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63983791/45375) with more background information:

***Quoting* an argument that contains *spaces* is a *general syntactic necessity, in *all* shells***, because ***unquoted* spaces are used to *separate multiple arguments***.

**It isn't only *spaces* that require quoting, but any of PowerShell's so-called *metacharacters*** (characters that, when used unquoted, have *syntactic function*); for instance, passing the path to a directory literally named `a;b` requires quoting as well, given that `;` would otherwise be interpreted as a *statement separator*.

- Note that PowerShell has *more* metacharacters than both `cmd.exe`; for the complete list, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375).

There are multiple **quoting *styles***:

- Since your path value is a ***literal*** - it contains no variable references or expressions - a [**verbatim** (single-quoted) string (**`'...'`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) is the best choice.

  `cd 'C:\Users\Robert Inspiron14'`
- If your path contains **variables or subexpressions**, you must use an [**expandable** (double-quoted) string (**`"..."`**)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)<sup>[1]</sup>

  `cd "$HOME\Documents"`
- Another, **less common solution** is to ***individually* escape the space characters with `` ` ``**, the so-called *backtick*, PowerShell's escape character:

  `` cd C:\Users\Robert` Inspiron14 ``

Also note:

- PowerShell's **tab-completion** automatically **applies quoting as necessary**.
- If the **path of the *executable* (also) requires quoting** or is expressed via a a *variable*, it **must be invoked via `&`**, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), for syntactic reasons - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64413759/45375).
- **`cd..` is the name of a built-in *function* in PowerShell**, whose sole purpose is **to emulate `cmd.exe`'s (questionably permissive) behavior** (see below); the function performs a syntactically correct `Set-Location ..` call (verify by executing `${function:cd..}`), with a space separating the command name from its argument.

---

#### Contrast with `cmd.exe`:

Unfortunately, **`cmd.exe`'s built-in `cd` command decided *not* to enforce its usual syntax rules**, and **enabled calls such as `cd C:\Program Files`.**

**It should never have done that**: While convenient at first glance, it constitutes a **problematic exception from the usual rules that invites confusion**.
Note that `cmd.exe`'s *tab completion* properly quotes arguments that contain spaces.

Similarly, **`cd..` was unfortunately allowed as as syntactically exceptional alternative to the correct `cd ..`** - see the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58252690/45375) for details.

---

<sup>[1] Note `"..."`-quoting isn't strictly necessary if you use *variable* references in a path, as long as any *literal* components do not require quoting; e.g., `$HOME\foo` is fine without quoting, whereas the `"` around `"$HOME\foo bar"` are required. With *subexpressions* ([`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--)), the [rules get more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42100211/45375), so the simplest approach is to *always* use `"..."`-quoting with them.</sup>