# What's the equivalent of cmd for powershell with ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, command-line, syntax

from https://www.poftut.com/ffmpeg-command-tutorial-examples-video-audio/

```
ffmpeg -i jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv
```

works in cmd but same on Powershell gives

```
Unexpected token '-i' in expression or statement.
```

what's then the right syntax ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As currently shown in your question, the command would work just fine in PowerShell.

```bash
# OK - executable name isn't quoted.
ffmpeg -i jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv
```

However, **if you *quote* the executable path, the problem surfaces**.

```bash
# FAILS, due to SYNTAX ERROR, because the path is (double)-quoted.
PS> "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -i jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv
Unexpected token '-i' in expression or statement.
```

**For *syntactic reasons*, PowerShell requires `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), to invoke executables whose paths are *quoted* and/or contain *variable references or subexpressions*.**

```bash
# OK - use of &, the call operator, required because of the quoted path.
& "C:\Program Files\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg" -i jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv
```

Or, via an environment variable:

```bash
# OK - use of &, the call operator, required because of the variable reference.
# (Double-quoting is optional in this case.)
& $env:ProgramFiles\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg -i jellyfish-3-mbps-hd-h264.mkv
```

**If you don't want to have to think about when `&` is actually *required*, you can simply *always* use it.**

The **syntactic need for `&`** stems from PowerShell having two fundamental parsing modes and is explained in detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066651/45375).

Comment: weird I have not seen that mentioned until now in Powershell articles I read, thanks.

Comment: @user310291, yes, it isn't obvious, and while the need for `&` also applies to PowerShell commands supplied via quoted strings or variables, it is most likely to occur when calling external programs. There is a pending proposal to introduce a help topic that covers all special considerations that apply when calling external programs: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5152