# Creating a GitHub Action which runs a Powershell script on a Windows host

Tags: windows, powershell, github-actions

My GitHub Actions workflow "runs-on" **windows-latest**. I want a custom Action which executes a PowerShell (core or legacy is fine) script. I have a parallel action that runs on Linux and MacOS. So, my .github/actions/install-tf-win directory contains this action.yml

```yaml
name: install_tf_win
description: installs Terraform/TerraGrunt for Windows
runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - run: install-tf-win\install-tf-win.ps1
      shell: pwsh
```

The directory also contains install-tf-win.ps1. I have tried all sorts of variations on that run statement. Starting with "&" and without, variations in paths used with forwards and backwards slashes. I originally started with $GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/install-tf-win.ps1 (works for Linux/MacOS), however it seemed that GITHUB_ACTION_PATH was getting evaluated to be an empty string and then there were complaints about /install-tf-win.ps1 not being found. I tried both pwsh and powershell for the shell key value.

The form shown above results in this error:

```
Run ./.github/actions/install-tf-win
install-tf-win\install-tf-win.ps1: D:\a\_temp\c1d3d7fa-074b-4f90-ade0-799dcebd84ec.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  install-tf-win\install-tf-win.ps1
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The module 'install-tf-win' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module
     | install-tf-win'.
```

I can obviously code my way around this by just putting the PowerShell statements in a step. But, the documentation suggests this should work. https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsshell .

So, how do I get this to work, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The error message implies that you cannot refer to your script with a *relative* path:**

The command is passed to `pwsh`, PowerShell [Core]'s [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), via its **`-Command` (`-c`) parameter**, which **interprets the `install-tf-win` part of

`install-tf-win\install-tf-win.ps1` as a *module name*** rather than as a *subdirectory* in the *absence* of an actual subdirectory by that name *on Windows*<sup>[1]</sup>, so the implication is that such a path *doesn't exist*.

**The [linked documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/metadata-syntax-for-github-actions#runsstepsrun), suggests that you need an absolute path**, based on the `GITHUB_ACTION_PATH` *environment* variable, which in PowerShell must be referenced as `$env:GITHUB_ACTION_PATH` (untested):

```
# ...
    - run: '& $env:GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/install-tf-win/install-tf-win.ps1'
      shell: pwsh
```

Note:

- The need to use `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), which is a syntactic necessity due to the script path containing a(n environment-)*variable reference*; the same would apply if the path were *quoted* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64413759/45375) for background information.
- Since `&` is a metacharacter in YAML when used unquoted at the start of a value, the entire string is quoted. Single-quoting (`'...'`) is employed in this case, so that YAML doesn't interpret the contents of the string up front.

  - As an aside: The implication of `'...'`-quoting working (as confirmed by Kevin, the OP) is that when `pwsh -c` is ultimately called on Windows, the string's content is (properly) *double-quoted* (`"..."`), because PowerShell's CLI only recognizes `"` as having *syntactic* function for command-line argument parsing. By contrast, a `'...'`-quoted `-c` argument would be interpreted as a *verbatim string* rather than as a command, causing its content to be simply *echoed*.

---

**[1] How PowerShell interprets a path such as `foo\bar.ps1` when executed as a *command*, as of PowerShell 7.1**

Interpreted as a command - both inside a PowerShell session and via the `-Command` / `-c` parameter of the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), as used by GitHub Actions - **the form `foo\bar.ps1` is ambiguous**:

- It could refer to a *module* named `foo`, and its `bar.ps1` *command* (even though module commands don't have `.ps1` name extensions).
- It could refer to a *subdirectory* `foo` and file `bar.ps1` in it.

  - This applies to *Windows only*:

    - PowerShell *first* interprets the path as a *file-system* path.
    - If the path *doesn't exist*, it *falls back* to interpreting it as a module-command reference.
  - On *Unix*-like platforms - even though PowerShell *generally* allows you to use `\` and `/` interchangeably as the path separator on all supported platforms - this particular path form is *always* interpreted as a *module* reference; in other words: you cannot use this syntax form to invoke a script this way (see below).
  - This surprising inconsistency is discussed in [GitHub issue #14307](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14307).

There are two **ways to avoid this ambiguity**, which work on *all* supported platforms; the following cause PowerShell to unequivocally treat the path as file-system script path:

- Use `/` instead of `\`: `foo/bar.ps1`
- Prefix the path with `.\` (or `./`): `.\foo\bar.ps1`

(Of course, you could also use a *full* path.)

Note that when the `-File` parameter of PowerShell's is used (rather than `-Command` / `-c`), this ambiguity doesn't arise, as the argument is then *always* considered a (potentially relative) file-system path, even on Unix-like platforms, irrespective of whether you use `\` or `/`.

Comment: The form - run: '& $env:GITHUB_ACTION_PATH/install-tf-win/install-tf-win.ps1'
      shell: pwsh
worked. It is important to note that the additional path segment "/install-tf-win/" is not required for the equivalent for Linux or MacOS.