# Copying a file with robocopy (long name and path, and many spaces) - Missing argument

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I tried to copy a file with robocopy, but the PowerShell gives me an error "MissingArgument":

```
robocopy D:\Enciclopedia` mia\Tutorial` FATTI` DA` ME\Internet\Google\Limitare` permessi` di` alcune` celle` o` colonne` o` righe` in` Google` Sheets C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop Protect,` hide,` and` edit` sheets` -` Computer` (Proteggere,` limitare` permessi` di` alcune` celle` o` colonne` o` righe` in` Google` Sheets)` -` Docs` Editors` Help.pdf
```

File name:

```
Protect, hide, and edit sheets - Computer (Proteggere, limitare permessi di alcune celle o colonne o righe in Google Sheets) - Docs Editors Help.pdf
```

File path:

```
D:\Enciclopedia mia\Tutorial FATTI DA ME\Internet\Google\Limitare permessi di alcune celle o colonne o righe in Google Sheets
```

I used the same command on a different file, and it works perfectly:

```
robocopy C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\Rapida C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\a BULK` MIO.pdf
```

Could you tell me how can I overcome this problem please?

Comment: Try quoting the paths (`'C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop\a BULK MIO.pdf'`) instead of adding all those backticks. (altough this first extremely long path and filename can cause trouble). Why such LOOOOOOOONG names anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth heeding [Theo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) advice: **enclosing your file names** that contain spaces and other special characters either in **single quotes (`'...'`, for *verbatim* values)** or **double quotes (`"..."`, if you need *string interpolation*)** is the simplest solution.<sup>[1]</sup>

While **escaping characters *individually* with `` ` ``**, without enclosing quoting does work, it's **visually less obvious** and, as in your case, it is **easy to miss characters that need escaping**:

In PowerShell `,`, `(`, and `)` are also metacharacters that require escaping in order to be interpreted verbatim, and you neglected to escape them.

Therefore, escape as follows, using `Write-Output` as an example command to demonstrate that the names are parsed correctly:

```
PS> Write-Output D:\Enciclopedia` mia\Tutorial` FATTI` DA` ME\Internet\Google\Limitare` permessi` di` alcune` celle` o` colonne` o` righe` in` Google` Sheets C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop` Protect`,` hide`,` and` edit` sheets` -` Computer` `(Proteggere`,` limitare` permessi` di` alcune` celle` o` colonne` o` righe` in` Google` Sheets`)` -` Docs` Editors` Help.pdf

D:\Enciclopedia mia\Tutorial FATTI DA ME\Internet\Google\Limitare permessi di alcune celle o colonne o righe in Google Sheets
C:\Users\Raffaele\Desktop Protect, hide, and edit sheets - Computer (Proteggere, limitare permessi di alcune celle o colonne o righe in Google Sheets) - Docs Editors Help.pdf
```

**List of metacharacters that require individual escaping in unquoted command arguments:**

```
<space> ' " ` , ; ( ) { } | & < > @ #
```

Note:

- Of these, `< > @ #` are only special at the *start* of an argument.
- *Situationally*, `.` (dot) requires escaping too, namely if the argument can syntactically be interpreted as accessing a variable's property (e.g., `Write-Output $env:computername.csv` outputs nothing - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66161666/45375)).
- If you want a `$` to be treated verbatim rather than refer to a variable or subexpression, you must escape it too.
- For a complete overview of how unquoted command arguments are parsed in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375).

---

<sup>[1] See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55614306/45375) for an overview of **PowerShell string literals** in general, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for the rules of string interpolation in so-called **expandable strings** (`"..."`), specifically.</sup>