# "Unrecognized token in source text" error while installing TailwindCSS using npm command

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm-install, tailwind-css

this is the error I am getting while installing.
my node is 13.x.x
and npm is 7.x.x

[image]

Comment: Can you just try running the command "npm i tailwindcss" once.

Comment: PowerShell has _more_ [metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) (characters with special meaning) than other shells, notably including `@ { } , ;`. For them to be used _verbatim_, they must be individually `\``-escaped or enclosed in a quoted string. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely related to PowerShell, as `@` is a [metacharacter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) there.

Try running the command with quotes around `@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat`.

```sh
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat" postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```