# passing guid and path to bcdedit /set as a variable

Tags: powershell, automation, powershell-remoting, bcdedit

I need to run these 4 commands to boot a new image into a device:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Describe"
bcdedit /set {guid} osdevice vhd=somepath 
bcdedit /set {guid} device vhd=somepath
bcdedit /default {$guid}
```

To automate my script, I want to extract the guid/identifier returned as output from the first command and pass it as a parameter to the other 3 commands.
Right now, I'm doing it in this way:

```
$guid = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Describe""}

#output
#$guid = This entry was successfully copied to {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}

$guid = $guid.Replace("This entry was successfully copied to {","")
$guid = $guid.Replace("}","")

$path1 = "xxx/xxxx/...."

#passing the guid and path as inputs
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "bcdedit /set {$guid} osdevice vhd=$path1"}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "bcdedit /set {$guid} device vhd=$path1"}
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "bcdedit /default {$guid} "}
```

But, each time I get an error:

**The element data type is not recognized, or does not apply to the specified entry.
Run "bcdedit /?" for command line assistance.
Element not found**

This works fine when I manually copy and paste the path in the UI, but I'm not sure how I can automate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68187510/45375) to your prior question, there is no need to use `cmd /c` in order to invoke `bcdedit` - all that is needed is to *quote* literal arguments that contain `{` and `}`, because these characters, when used unquoted, have special meaning in PowerShell.

  - Calling via `cmd /c` is not only inefficient (though in practice that will hardly matter), but can also introduce quoting headaches.<sup>[1]</sup>
- A script block passed to `Invoke-Command -ComputerName ...` executes *remotely* and therefore has no access to the *caller's* variables; the simplest way to include variable values from the caller's scope is via the `$using:` scope (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60012780/45375)).

Therefore:

```sh
$guid = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 
  bcdedit /copy '{current}' /d "Describe" 
}

# Extract the GUID from the success message, which has the form
# "This entry was successfully copied to {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"
$guid = '{' + ($guid -split '[{}]')[1] + '}'

$path1 = "xxx/xxxx/...."

# Passing the guid and path as inputs, which must
# be done via the $using: scope.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 
  bcdedit /set $using:guid osdevice vhd=$using:path1
  bcdedit /set $using:guid vhd=$using:path1
  bcdedit /default $using:guid
}
```

---

<sup>[1] For instance, `cmd /c "bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Describe""` doesn't work the way you think it does; it would have to be `` cmd /c "bcdedit /copy {current} /d `"Describe`"" ``</sup>