# How to escape @ within a string in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, curl, escaping

I'm trying to send a HTML request via cURL in PowerShell. The code in question:

```
$command = 'curl -d @request.txt -o testoutput.xml -X "POST" -H @header.txt -u "username:password" "URL"'
Invoke-Expression $command
```

The HTML Body (-d) and Header (-H) need to be read from files, hence the @ before the filenames.

In order for this to work, I need to escape the @ so PowerShell doesn't interpret it as a splat operator - and that's my problem, nothing I've tried so far worked:

- putting it in single quotes
- here document (@" "@)
- here string (@' '@)
- using string templates with placeholders ("{0}request.txt" -f "@")
- Unicode escape ("`u{0040}request.txt")

How do I escape the @ correctly? Or am I on the wrong path entirely? (I'm new to PowerShell sorry)

Comment: Use `--%`: `curl --% -d @request.txt -o testoutput.xml -X "POST" -H @header.txt -u "username:password" "URL"` - this will prevent the PowerShell parser from trying to evaluate anything following it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375); definitely [don't use it to invoke an external program or PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57966347/45375).

Therefore:

- invoke `curl` *directly*
- and *quote* PowerShell *metacharacters* such as `@` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375) for the full list) - either *individually*, with `` ` `` (e.g., `` `@ ``), or by enclosing the entire argument in quotes (`'...'` or `"..."`, as appropriate).

```sh
curl -d `@request.txt -o testoutput.xml -X "POST" -H @header.txt -u "username:password" "URL"
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The primary concern about `Invoke-Expression` use is one of *security*: unwanted execution of (additional) commands potentially injected into the string passed to it.

In terms of *functionality*, `Invoke-Expression` is not only not *needed* for regular calls to external programs, it can create *quoting headaches*.

However, given that you're passing a `'...'` string to `Invoke-Expression`, quoting the `@` as `` `@ `` would have worked, as shown in this simple example:

```sh
# OK, but generally do NOT do this.
Invoke-Expression 'Write-Output `@'
```

Had you used a `"..."` string, the `` ` `` would have been "eaten" by the up-front parsing of such an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), based on the escaping rules explained in the conceptual [about_Quoting_Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules) help topic:

```sh
# BREAKS, because the ` is stripped before Invoke-Expression sees it.
Invoke-Expression "Write-Output `@"
```