# What is the significance of backslashes, backticks, and carets in various shells

Tags: docker, powershell, shell, command-prompt, line-continuation

I am following https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/#start-a-dev-mode-container on a Windows PC and am stuck here:

> Run the following command. We’ll explain what’s going on afterwards:

```
 docker run -dp 3000:3000 \
     -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" \
     node:12-alpine \
     sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

> If you are using PowerShell then use this command:

```
 docker run -dp 3000:3000 `
     -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" `
     node:12-alpine `
     sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
```

When using Command Prompt, I get errors (tried multiple variations as shown below), and when using PowerShell, I don't appear to get errors but am not running anything as showed when executing `docker ps`.
Note that I would rather use Command Prompt and not PowerShell as I could use Linux commands with ComandPrompt on my PC.

What is the significance of backslashes when using Dockers with Command Prompt (and tick marks with PowerShell for that matter)?

I have since found that `docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w /app -v "%cd%:/app" node:12-alpine sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"` works without errors (got rid of backslashes, put on one line, and used `%cd%` instead of `$(pwd)`), but would still like to know why using the exact script in the example results in errors.

**Using Command Prompt**

```
C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>docker run -dp 3000:3000 \
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>     -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" \
'-w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>     node:12-alpine \
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>     sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
sh: yarn: command not found

C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>docker run -dp 3000:3000 \ -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" \ node:12-alpine \ sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.

C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>docker run -dp 3000:3000 -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" node:12-alpine sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
docker: Error response from daemon: create $(pwd): "$(pwd)" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.

C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker\app>
```

**Using PowerShell**

```
PS C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker>  docker run -dp 3000:3000 `
>>      -w /app -v "$(pwd):/app" `
>>      node:12-alpine `
>>      sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
849af42e78d4ab09242fdd6c3d03bcf1b6b58de984c4485a441a2e2c88603767
PS C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
PS C:\Users\michael\Documents\Docker>
```

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "use Linux commands in command prompt"... But you'll need to look at `docker logs` to know why the container is actually failing (probably something bad in the yarn process)

Comment: @OneCricketeer, When installing git, installed tools to allow me to use `ls -l` instead of `dir`.

Comment: Sounds like you're using "Git Bash", which is not CMD. Basically, I'd consider that deprecated in favor of WSL2 overall

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Yes I was.  Through it might be causing problems (unfortunately it wasn't the culprit) but couldn't remember what it was called until seeing your comment.  Will checkout WSL2.  Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> would still like to know why using the exact script in the example results in errors.

Because **the command with the line-ending `\` characters is meant for *POSIX-compatible shells*** such as `bash`, not for `cmd.exe`

- **POSIX-compatible shells** (`sh`, `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`):

  - use `\` for line-continuation (continuing a command on the following line) and escaping in general.
  - use `$varName` to reference both environment and shell-only variables.
  - support `$(...)` for embedding the output from a command (`...`) in command lines (*command substitution*).
  - support both double-quoted (`"..."`, interpolating) and single-quoted (`'...'`, verbatim) strings; use `'\''` to - in effect - include a `'` inside `'...'`.
    (Additionally, in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`, there are the rarely used [ANSI C-quoted](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) strings, `$'...'`, and, in `bash` and `ksh`, perhaps even more rarely, [localizable strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation), `$"..."`).
- **`cmd.exe`**:

  - uses `^` for line-continuation and escaping in general (in unquoted arguments only).
  - uses `%varName%` to reference environment variables (the only variable type supported).
  - doesn't support command substitutions at all.
  - supports only `"..."` strings (interpolating).
- **PowerShell**:

  - uses `` ` `` (the backtick) for line-continuation and escaping in general.
  - uses `$env:varName` to reference environment variables, `$varName` to reference shell-only variables.
  - supports `$(...)`, called *subexpressions*, the equivalent of command substitutions (outside of double-quoted strings, `(...)` is usually sufficient).
  - supports both double-quoted (`"..."`, interpolating) and single-quoted (`'...'`, verbatim) strings; use `''` to embed a `'` inside `'...'`.
  - Note: A common pitfall is that PowerShell has more [metacharacters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) compared to both POSIX-compatible shells and `cmd.exe`, notably including `@ { } , ;`, which therefore require individual `` ` ``-escaping in unquoted arguments or embedding in quoted strings - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375).

Potential **line-continuation pitfall**: in all of the shells discussed, **the escape character must be the *very last character* on the line** - not even trailing (intra-line) whitespace is allowed (because the escape character would then apply to *it* rather than to the newline).

The information above is summarized in the following table:

| Feature | POSIX shells _ | cmd.exe _ | PowerShell _ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Line-continuation / escape character | Backslash (`\`) | Caret (`^`) | Backtick (`` ` ``) |
| Double-quoted strings (interpolating) | ✅ | ✅ | ✅ |
| Single-quoted strings (verbatim) | ✅ | ❌ | ✅ |
| Get / set environment variables | `$varName` / `export varName=...` | `%varName%` / `set varName=...` | `$env:varName` / `$env:varName = ...` |
| Get / set shell-only variables | `$varName`/ `varName=...` | ❌ (no such variables exist, but you can limit the scope of env. vars. with `setlocal`) | `$varName`/ `$varName = ...` |
| Command substitutions, subexpressions | `$(...)` | ❌ | `(...)` / `$(...)`, esp. in strings |

Note re ***setting* variables** with respect to ***whitespace* on either side of the `=` symbol**:

- In POSIX-like shells, there *must not* be whitespace around `=`.
- In `cmd.exe`, such whitespace is *significant* and becomes part of the variable / value name, and is therefore usually to be *avoided*.
- In PowerShell, such whitespace is *optional* - you *may* use it to enhance readability; any *string* value to be assigned requires *quoting* (e.g., `$var = 'hi!'`)

See also:

- https://hyperpolyglot.org/shell for a **much more comprehensive juxtaposition** of these shells, though note that - as of this writing - the information about PowerShell is incomplete.
- [Sage Pourpre's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794576/45375) for **links to the line-continuation documentation** of the respective shells.

Comment: Very comprehensive and high quality answer.  Especially helpful given the difficulty to search for information for these types of items.  Thank you.

Comment: Wow, you did pretty it up!  Ignore my part about input command substitutions as I was confused.

Comment: Got it, @user1032531. I've added a link to https://hyperpolyglot.org/shell, which is a comprehensive juxtaposition of these shells, though note that details are missing, esp. with respect to PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

This is character escaping.

The X Character (`\` for Bash, backtick for Powershell and `^` for Windows terminal )are used to remove any specific meanings to the next characters.

When used at the end of a line, this mean that the next character (The newline character) is completely ignored.

This keep the command essentially a one-line command from the point of view of the interpreter, but allow you to break it on multiple lines for better readability.

**References**

[Powershell - About special characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.1)

> Escape sequences begin with the backtick character [`` ` ``], known as the grave
> accent (ASCII 96), and are case-sensitive. The backtick character can
> also be referred to as the escape character.

[Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html)

3.1.2.1 Escape Character

> A non-quoted backslash `\` is the Bash escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that
> follows, with the exception of newline. If a `\newline` pair appears,
> and the backslash itself is not quoted, the `\newline` is treated as a
> line continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream and
> effectively ignored).

[How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> Escaping CR/LF line endings. The `^` escape character can be used to
> make long commands more readable by splitting them into multiple lines
> and escaping the Carriage Return + Line Feed (CR/LF) at the end of a
> line:
>
> ```
> ROBOCOPY \\FileServ1\e$\users ^
>   \\FileServ2\e$\BackupUsers ^
>   /COPYALL /B /SEC /MIR ^
>   /R:0 /W:0 /LOG:MyLogfile.txt /NFL /NDL
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> A couple of things to be aware of:
>
> A stray space at the end of a line (after the `^`) will break the
> command, this can be hard to spot unless you have a text editor that
> displays spaces and tab characters. If you want comment something out
> with REM, then EVERY line needs to be prefixed with REM. Alternatively
> if you use a double colon `::` as a REM comment, that will still parse
> the caret at the end of a line, so in the example above changing the
> first line to `:: ROBOCOPY…` will comment out the whole multi-line
> command.