# Why does backtick in Set-Content not create multiple lines?

Tags: powershell, escaping, newline

Both of these commands doesn't create multiple line text:

```
Set-Content .\test.md 'Hello`r`nWorld'
Set-Content .\test.md 'Hello\r\nWorld'
```

Only this can

```
Set-Content .\test.md @("Hello`nWorld")
```

Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **[Escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) such as `` `r`n `` only work inside `"..."`**, i.e, [*expandable* (interpolating) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings).

  - By contrast, **`'...'` strings (single-quoted)** are **[*verbatim* strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings)** that do *not* interpret their contents - even `` ` `` instances are used as verbatim (literally).
- **Only `` ` `` (the so-called backtick) serves as the escape character in PowerShell, not `\`**.

  - That is, in *both* `"..."` and `'...'` strings a `\` is a literal, i.e. used *verbatim*.
  - (However, `\` *is* the escape character in the context of [regexes (regular expressions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions), but it is then the *.NET regex engine* that interprets them, not PowerShell; e.g.,

    `` "`r" -match '\r' ``  is `$true`: the (interpolated) *literal* CR char. matched its escaped *regex* representation).

Note: `` ` ``-escaping also works in *unquoted* tokens, but only if they serve as *command arguments*; e.g., `` Write-Output line1`r`nline2 `` is equivalent to `` "line1`r`nline2" ``.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- It is the fact that `` "Hello`nWorld" `` in your last command is a `"..."` string that made it work.

  - By contrast, enclosing the string in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), is *incidental* to the solution. ([`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s (positionally implied) `-Value` parameter is *array*-valued anyway (`System.Object[]`), so even a *single* string getting passed is coerced to an array).
- Finally, note that `Set-Content` by default *adds a trailing, platform-native newline* to the output file; use `-NoNewLine` to suppress that, but note that doing so also places no newline *between* the (string representations of) *multiple* input objects, if applicable (in your case there's only *one*).

Therefore (note the `-NoNewLine` and the trailing `` `n ``):

```bash
Set-Content -NoNewLine .\test.md "Hello`nWorld`n"
```

---

##### Optional reading: design rationale for PowerShell's behavior:

> Why doesn't PowerShell use the **backslash (`\`) as the escape character**, like other languages?

Because PowerShell must (also) function on **Windows** (it started out as Windows-only), **use of `\` as the escape character** - as known from Unix (POSIX-compatible) shells such as Bash - is ***not* an option**, given that **`\` is used as the *path separator* on Windows.**

If `\` *were* the escape character, you'd have to use `Get-ChildItem C:\\Windows\\System32` instead of `Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32`, which is obviously impractical in a *shell*, where dealing with file-system paths is very common.

Thus, **a *different* character had to be chosen**, which turned out to be **`` ` ``, the so-called *backtick***: At least on US keyboards, it is easy to type (just like `\`), and it has the benefit of occurring rarely (as itself) in real-world strings, so that the need to *escape* it rarely arises.

Note that the much older legacy shell on Windows, `cmd.exe`, too had to pick a different character: it chose `^`, the so-called *caret*.

> Why doesn't it use **single quote and double quote interchangeably**, like other languages?

Different languages made different design choices, but in making `"..."` strings interpolating, but `'...'` strings *not*, **PowerShell *did* follow existing languages here**, namely that of **POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash**.
As an improvement on the latter PowerShell also supports embedding verbatim `'` inside `'...'`, escaped as `''` (e.g., `'6'' tall'`)

Given PowerShell's commitment to backward compatibility, this behavior won't change, especially given how fundamental it is to the language.

*Conceptually* speaking, you could argue that the aspect of what *quoting character* a string uses should be separate from whether it is *interpolating*, so that you'd be free to situationally choose one or the other quoting style for syntactic convenience, while *separately* controlling whether interpolation should occur.

Thus, *hypothetically*, PowerShell *could* have used a separate sigil to make a string interpolating, say `$"..."` and `$'...'` (similar to what C# now offers, though it notably only has *one* string-quoting style).
(As an aside: Bash and Ksh *do* have this syntax form, but it serves a different purpose (localization of strings) and is rarely used in pratice).

In practice, however, once you know how `"..."` and `'...'` work in PowerShell, it isn't hard to make them work as intended.

---

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794580/45375) for a **juxtaposition of PowerShell, `cmd.exe`, and POSIX-compatible shells** with respect to fundamental features.