# POST Request with CSV String using Curl on Windows

Tags: bash, powershell, curl

I am using cURL on Windows by attempting to use two shells with varying results(Powershell, Git Bash).

I want to POST a CSV string to an API. I know this API works because I have tested it in Python, however I cannot get it to work in the shell.

Example:

Powershell (Curl Version 8.0.1)

```
C:\Windows\System32\curl.exe -k 
 "https://website.com" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-raw $"LATITUDE,LONGITUDE\n53.3737131,-1.4704939\n53.3742428,-1.4677477\n53.3745646,-1.467576\n53.3758092,-1.4665675\n"
```

Git Bash (Curl Version 7.80)

```
$ curl -k 'https://website.com' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' --data-raw
$'LATITUDE,LONGITUDE\n53.3737131,-1.4704939\n53.3742428,-1.4677477\n53.3745646,-1.467576\n53.3758092,-1.4665675\n'
```

The Git Bash solution works.

The API is telling me I am missing the LATITUDE column in my CSV string. Without going into specifics on the API (since I know it works) is there something I could be missing in my curl request that is causing this CSV string to be malformed when sent?

Comment: Probably this is just a mistake when editing to post here, but there is a `'` missing at the end of the website string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are no `$"..."` strings in PowerShell**<sup>[1]</sup> (you seem to be thinking of an analog to [ANSI C-quoted strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting), `$'...'`, supported in some POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash).

Simply use `"..."`, i.e. an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), in which you can use [escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) such as `` `n `` to represent a *newline* (the equivalent of `\n` inside `$'...'` in Bash, for instance - note that PowerShell's escape character is `` ` ``, the so-called backtick)<sup>[2]</sup>.

However, note that *inside* `"..."` strings `$` is also special - it enables embedding variable reference and subexpressions to be expanded (interpolated) - so any `$` chars. to be treated *verbatim* must be escaped as `` `$ ``.

If you need neither escape sequences nor interpolation, use `'...'`, i.e. [verbatim (single-quoted) strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) instead (their only escaping requirement is that *embedded* `'` must be escaped as `''`).

Therefore:

```bash
# From PowerShell.
# Note the `n instances in lieu of \n in the final, "..."-enclosed argument.
curl.exe -k 'https://website.com' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' `
  --data-raw "LATITUDE,LONGITUDE`n53.3737131,-1.4704939`n53.3742428,-1.4677477`n53.3745646,-1.467576`n53.3758092,-1.4665675`n"
```

---

<sup>[1] In a command argument, the `$` is simply *prepended verbatim* to whatever the subsequent `"..."` string expands; e.g., `Write-Output $"foo"` outputs verbatim `$foo`. The same applies analogously to following `$` with `'...'` (single quotes)</sup>

<sup>[2] As for why PowerShell didn't choose `\` as the escape character: Since `\` is the *path separator* on Windows (and PowerShell has Windows-only roots), this would have made specifying file-system paths quite cumbersome, due to the resulting need to escape such - verbatim - separators (e.g. `C:\\Foo\\Bar` to refer to `C:\Foo\Bar`). See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74211220/45375) for a detailed discussion.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794580/45375) compares the escape characters, string literal types, and variable-reference syntaxes between PowerShell, `cmd.exe`, and POSIX-compatible shells.</sup>

Comment: Worked like a charm. thank you for your help. I know Bash far better than Powershell. Very strange design that they went and used a backtick for an escape sequence instead of the classic ```\```

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Coldchain9; my pleasure. As for why ``\`` wasn't chosen as the escape character: see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74211220/45375).

Comment: Thanks for sharing bonus information! :) Additionally, this came to mind: What major changes would be necessary when using ```cmd``` vs ```powershell```? Seems like the pattern is different there as well.

Comment: @Coldchain9, `cmd.exe` and PowerShell are fundamentally different beasts. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794580/45375) compares the escape characters, string literal types, and variable-reference syntaxes between PowerShell, cmd.exe, and POSIX-compatible shells, and may be a starting point.