# Powershell script error when running a gcloud command to bind tag to Firestore Database

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, terraform, azure-powershell

I am running a pipeline that uses a powershell script and I need to bind a tag I created to my Firestore database in Google Cloud Platform

the gcloud command to do this is as follows:

```
gcloud resource-manager tags bindings create --tag-value=$value --parent=//firestore.googleapis.com/projects/$projectID/databases/\(default\) --location=$location
```

I have tested this in Google CLI and it works. However when running it in my powershell script I am encountering the error below

```
 default\: /__w/1/build-bundle-00x-00x-general-extract/infra/00x-00x-general/.terraform/modules/gcp_firestore_enable_ttl/scripts/enable_ttl.ps1:60
 Line |
   60 |  … store.googleapis.com/projects/$projectID/databases/\(default\) --loca …
      |                                                         ~~~~~~~~
      | The term 'default\' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
      | function, script file, or executable program. Check the
      | spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
      | the path is correct and try again.
```

I have tried the command using bash script and Google Command Line Interface and works as intended with no errors. I am only experiencing this error when using powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

**In PowerShell, only `` ` `` (the so-called backtick) serves as the escape character, not `\`**.

- That is, `\` has no special meaning to PowerShell and is used *verbatim*.

Therefore, it must be `` `(default`) ``, not `\(default\)` in order to designate the unquoted use of `(` and `)` as verbatim, i.e. to pass verbatim string `(default)`:

```
# Note the `(default`) instead of `\(default\)`
gcloud resource-manager tags bindings create --tag-value=$value --parent=//firestore.googleapis.com/projects/$projectID/databases/`(default`) --location=$location
```

Alternatively, use *quoting*; since you're referencing a variable as part of the argument, you must use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings):

```
# "..." around the whole argument
gcloud resource-manager tags bindings create --tag-value=$value "--parent=//firestore.googleapis.com/projects/$projectID/databases/(default)" --location=$location
```

Note:

- *Partial* quoting would work too; by quoting only the `(default)` part, you can use a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings):

  ```
  --parent=//firestore.googleapis.com/projects/$projectID/databases/'(default)'
  ```
- However, note that this only works if the argument *starts* with an *unquoted* token (which is true here); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65380907/45375) for background information.

---

As for why PowerShell didn't choose `\` as the escape character:

- Since `\` is the *path separator* on Windows (and PowerShell has Windows-only roots), this would have made specifying file-system paths quite cumbersome, due to the resulting need to escape such separators (e.g. `C:\\Foo\\Bar` to refer to `C:\Foo\Bar`). See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74211220/45375) for a detailed discussion.