# Set-ItemProperty is failing to add item to PATH

Tags: windows, powershell, path

**What specific syntax must be changed in the PowerShell 5 script below in order to successfully add `$HOME\\myapphome\\` to the system PATH in a Windows 11 server?**

The following script named `.\addMyPath.ps1` successfully prints out the correct value for `myapp version` and also prints out the correct value for `Write-Output $newpath` including `$HOME\\myapphome\\` when the following script is run as `.\addMyPath.ps1`.

```
$env:Path += ";$HOME\\myapphome\\"
Write-Output "About to prepend myapp to path permanently. "
$aloc="$HOME\\myapphome\\"
$oldpath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path
$newpath = "$aloc;$oldpath"
Write-Output "About to print newpath "
Write-Output $newpath
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newpath
echo "About to print myapp cli version command output: "
myapp version
```

But when we close that PowerShell window and then open a new PowerShell window, we get the following error, which indicates that `myapp` was not permanently added to the PATH.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> myapp version
myapp : The term 'myapp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ myapp version
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (myapp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Similarly, running `$env:PATH` from the new PowerShell window also fails to include `$HOME\\myapphome\\` in the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

There are two problems with your code, which the snippet below corrects:

- After modifying the persistent definition of the `PATH` environment variable, you forgot to notify the Windows shell of the update.
- By using [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) to retrieve the old persisted value from the registry and by basing the new persisted value on that, you inadvertently converted the *expandable* old value to a *static* one.

```
$aloc="$HOME\myapphome"

# Update the in-process PATH value.
$env:Path += ";$aloc"

"About to prepend myapp to path permanently. "
# Get the *unexpanded* value of the machine-level PATH environment variable 
# from the registry.
$oldpath = (Get-Item 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment').GetValue('Path', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
$newpath = "$aloc;$oldpath"

"About to print newpath "
$newpath
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newpath
echo "About to print myapp cli version command output: "
myapp version

# Now that the registry has been updated, the Windows shell must be
# notified of the update.
# A non-disruptive approach is to create and delete a persistent dummy variable 
# via [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable().
[string] $dummyEnvVarName = New-Guid
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyEnvVarName, 'dummy', 'User')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyEnvVarName, $null, 'User')
```

Note:

- Read on for an explanation and background information.
- For a custom convenience function (`Add-Path`) that robustly updates the persistent `PATH` environment variable (in either scope) with automatic in-process updating and notification of the Windows shell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375).

---

##### Explanation and background information:

- As an aside (the problem is benign, because duplicated path separators are quietly tolerated):

  - `\` has no special meaning to PowerShell, so it never needs escaping as `\\` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76867883/45375) for background information).
- **If you modify environment variables *via the registry***, you need to **ensure that the [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) is *notified of the update***. (The Windows shell is the system GUI component that comprises the Start Menu, the Desktop, the taskbar, and File Explorer.)

  - After such a notification, new processes launched *via the Window shell* see the modified environment (as opposed to new processes launched from preexisting processes that predate the modification, in which case they inherit this old environment).

Because updating the registry with [`Set-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty) does *not* perform this notification, your newly launched processes didn't see the modification.

**Solution options**:

- A simple, but visually disruptive solution that also makes you lose the state of your File Explorer windows is to forcefully terminate all  `explorer` processes, which forces the Windows shell to reload, in the course of which the updated environment-variable definitions are read from the registry:

  ```
  Stop-Process -Name explorer
  ```
- A less disruptive, but more cumbersome solution is to rely on the fact that  [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) *does* implicitly perform this notification, and that that it causes the Windows shell to reload *all* environment variables.

  ```
  # Create and delete a persistent dummy variable via
  # [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(), which causes the 
  # Windows shell to reload the environment.
  [string] $dummyEnvVarName = New-Guid
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyEnvVarName, 'dummy', 'User')
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyEnvVarName, $null, 'User')
  ```

  - As discussed next, directly using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` to update `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-based environment variables is unfortunately currently *not* an option.
- As of .NET 8, **direct use of [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) is only safe for *static* persistent environment variables** (stored in the registry as `REG_SZ`), not for *expandable* ones such as `PATH` (stored as `REG_EXPAND_SZ`):

  ```
  # !! AVOID for REG_EXPAND_SZ env. vars. such as PATH
  # !! This informs the shell of an updated environment,
  # !! but converts *expandable* (REG_EXPAND_SZ-based_
  # !! environment variables to *static* ones (REG_SZ).
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $newPath, 'Machine')
  ```

  - The `PATH` environment variables are originally created as registry values of type `REG_EPXAND_SZ`, which means that they may be defined in terms of *other* environment variables. E.g., the unexpanded value of the `TEMP` user-level variable in the registry is `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`.
  - As of .NET 8, `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` does *not* support `REG_EPXAND_SZ` environment variables and potentially *corrupts* them - see next section.

---

##### Incomplete support for managing persistent environment variables in .NET and PowerShell:

- **The *.NET* environment-variable APIs have *incomplete and potentially destructive* support for `REG_EXPAND_SZ` environment variables (which `PATH` is a notable example of)**, as of .NET 8:

  - `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()` *invariably* returns the *already expanded* value of a given `REG_EXPAND_SZ` environment variable. While that is appropriate for *using* the variable value, it isn't for *updating* it, because in the latter case you want to modify the *unexpanded* value.
  - What's worse, `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` invariably (re)creates `REG_SZ` values, i.e. *non*-expandable environment variables, so if you use this method to update `Path`, the latter becomes a *static value*.

    - While replacing an expandable value with a statically *expanded* one *may or may not* cause problems later, you *will* break things if you set an *unexpanded* value (because the embedded environment-variable references then won't get expanded).
  - This problematic behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #1442](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1442) - unfortunately, no action has been taken since 2019, when the issue was reported.
  - The **workaround** is to **use the *registry* .NET APIs instead**, which, however, is not only more cumbersome, but also requires manually notifying the Windows shell of the update.
- **On the *PowerShell side*, support is *incomplete* too**, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.3.6:

  - In terms of PowerShell-native *environment-variable* features:

    - Updating the *persistent* definitions of environment variables is *unsupported*.
    - The [`Env:` drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Provider) and its associated namespace variable notation (e.g., `$env:PATH`) support querying the *expanded*, *in-process* values only.
    - A previous discussion about providing cmdlets that manage persistent environment variables has not (yet) led to a solution that ships with PowerShell itself. A [prototype implementation](https://github.com/JamesWTruher/EnvironmentVariableModule) of *new cmdlets* is available via the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/EnvironmentVariableCmdlet/), but it seems to languish and, most importantly, *it too lacks support for `REG_EXPAND_SZ` environment variables*.
  - In terms of PowerShell-native *registry* features:

    - [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) and [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) also currently *invariably* return the *expanded* value.

      - However, a future improvement to allow requesting the *unexpanded* value has been green-lit, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet - see [GitHub issue #16812](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16812).
      - For now, to get the *unexpanded* value you must use the .NET registry APIs directly, though you can combine them with [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item):

        ```
         (Get-Item `
            'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
         ).GetValue('Path', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
        ```
    - On the plus side, [`Set-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty) *does* implicitly preserve an existing `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry value as such on updating (to *create* a value as such, use `-Type ExpandString`).