# Computer can't find installed libraries

Tags: python, powershell, import, package, path-variables

I use VSCode
Anytime I install a python library, I get this notification:

> WARNING: The scripts auto-py-to-exe.exe and autopytoexe.exe are
> installed in 'C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH

But I've added that to path.
If I run:

```
echo $env:PATH
```

I get

```
C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts:C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows
```

suggesting that I've added said path.

I'm confused because I can't run packages from the CLI directly, even though importing them works.

I added the path manually and I've tried removing it but that doesn't work.
Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: There is typo - you have colon,not semi-colon at the end `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts:`

Comment: Holy shit you were right, I had to change my path from "PATH": "C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\Scripts:${env:PATH}" to "PATH": "C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\Scripts;${env:PATH}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own solution is effective in principle - **`;` is the required separator on Windows** -  except that your statement isn't valid PowerShell code, and that `\` chars. don't need escaping as `\\` in PowerShell; also, you can express the new directory path more generically using the `LOCALAPPDATA` [environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables); therefore:

```
$newDir = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\Scripts"
$env:PATH = "$newDir;$env:PATH"
```

The above modifies `$env:PATH` only for the *current session* (process).
To also ***persist* this change on Windows** - so that future sessions see it too:

- *Interactively*, run `sysmd.cpl`, select the `Advanced` tab, and click on `Environment Variables...`, then add the value of `$newDir` to the desired scope; since your directory path is *user-specific*, add it to the `User variables for <username>` list.
- *Programmatically*, this is surprisingly difficult to do *robustly*:

  - *If you don't mind converting the original `REG_EXPAND_SZ` definition to a static `REG_SZ` one*, you can use [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) (to target the *machine*-level definition of the variable, change `'User'` to `'Machine'`, but not that doing so requires *elevation* (running as administrator):

    ```
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
      'PATH',
      ($newDir + ';' + [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'User')), 
      'User'
    )
    ```
  - While this *typically* has no ill effects, it *can*; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76876384/45375) for background information and a robust alternative; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) wraps the robust alternative in a helper function, `Add-Path`, and explains why `setx.exe` should be avoided for `PATH` updates.
  - A simpler programmatic alternative, which also works on Unix-like platforms, is to add the above statements to your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) file, but note that only PowerShell sessions and programs launched from them will then see the updated `PATH`, and that profile-loading can be suppressed by launching a PowerShell session via the `-NoProfile` CLI parameter (the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe -NoProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for *Windows PowerShell*, [`pwsh -NoProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md))

Note that **.NET *cannot* offer APIs for *persistent* environment-variable definitions on *Unix*-like platforms**, because there's no *unified* mechanism across all of them.

---

##### ***Cross-platform* background information on the `PATH` environment variable**:

- The ***platform-specific* separator** used in the list of directory paths stored in the special **`PATH` environment variable** is:

  - `;` on *Windows*
  - `:` on *Unix*-like platforms
- **In *cross-platform* scripting, make changes to `PATH` as follows** in PowerShell:

  - Use `$env:PATH` - all uppercase - because environment-variable access is case-*sensitive* on *Unix*-like platforms, and the special variable's name is indeed `PATH` there.

    - On *Windows*, the official name is `Path`, but because environment-variable access is case-*insensitive*, any case variation and therefore also `PATH` works.
  - Use the - confusingly named - [`[System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.PathSeparator) property to get the platform-native separator.
  - In forming *directory paths* to add, use the platform-native *file-system path separator*, which .NET reflects in the - equally unfortunately named - [`[System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) property.

    - PowerShell's [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet and .NET's [`[System.IO.Path]::Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) method, when given *components* of a path, *implicitly* use the platform-native separator, which is `\` on Windows, and `/` on Unix-like platforms.

      - Note that `\` has *no* special meaning in PowerShell (and neither in `cmd.exe`) so there is *no* need to represent *literal* `\` characters as `\\`  (however, in the context of file-system paths, such accidentally duplicated separators are generally still accepted).
    - On *Windows*, you could alternatively use `/` as well, which is safe to use in the context of `PATH` as well as PowerShell-native commands.

      - .NET reflects this fact via the [`[System.IO.Path]::AltDirectorySeparatorChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar) property
      - However, programs / scripts examining `$env:PATH` for *existing* entries are likely to assume `\`, so it's best to use the platform-native separator.
      - Also, generally speaking, there are still Windows contexts where `/` *doesn't* work, such as in `cmd.exe` and COM APIs.
  - Generally, aim to express your directory paths in terms of *environment* / *well-known* directories, to be resolved to *literals* paths *at the time of adding* entries:

    - E.g., the `C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local` part of your path could be replaced with environment variable `$env:LOCALAPPDATA`
    - However, for *cross-platform* use it's best to use *platform-agnostic abstractions*, as provided - within limits - by [`[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetFolderPath)

      - E.g., the platform-agnostic equivalent of the above is:

        ```
        [Environment]::GetFolderPath('LocalApplicationData')
        ```
    - Since use of `[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath()` isn't very PowerShell-friendly, [GitHub issue #6966](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6966) asks for surfacing known folders platform-agnostically via a separate namespace / provider, e.g. `$sf:LocalApplicationData` (`sf` standing for *s*pecial *f*older).

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed explanation. I don't understand some of it because I'm not too familiar with PowerShell, but I think I understand the basic idea. Thank you for taking the time to write this!

Comment: You're awesome. You're not, by any chance, looking for youngblood to take under your wing, are you? Either way, thank you for your help. Answer accepted. Yes this is a HIMYM reference. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the path I specified. I was sure everyone asked me to use a colon but at @buran 's suggestion, I changed the colon right before `"${env:PATH}"` to a semi-colon and that was it.

old path:

```
 "PATH": "C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\Scripts:${env:PATH}"
```

new path:

```
"PATH": "C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\Scripts;${env:PATH}"
```