# helm error when trying to connect to kubernetes cluster

Tags: powershell, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

When trying to connect to a Kubernetes Cluster in Powershell:

```
helm repo add gitlab https://charts.gitlab.io
helm repo update
helm upgrade --install 'xxxxx' gitlab/gitlab-agent \
    --namespace gitlab-agent-'agent name' \
    --create-namespace \
    --set image.tag='tag name' \
    --set config.token='token-info' \
    --set config.kasAddress=wss://kas.gitlab.com
```

I get this error:

> "helm upgrade" requires 2 arguments.

Additionally, I got an error that says

> '--set' is not a recognized as an internal or external command"
>
> Usage:  helm upgrade [RELEASE] [CHART] [flags]

I tried entering the commands separately in PowerShell but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

- **`\` only works for *line-continuation* in *POSIX-compatible shells*** such as Bash.
- In PowerShell, `\` has *no* special meaning; **PowerShell's escape character is `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*** - see [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters)

Therefore:

```bash
# ...
helm upgrade --install 'xxxxx' gitlab/gitlab-agent `
    --namespace gitlab-agent-'agent name' `
    --create-namespace `
    --set image.tag='tag name' `
    --set config.token='token-info' `
    --set config.kasAddress=wss://kas.gitlab.com
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68794580/45375) for a **juxtaposition of POSIX-compatible shells, PowerShell and `cmd.exe`** with respect to escape characters, string literals, (environment) variables, and command substitutions (subexpressions).