# aws cli command in PowerShell gives "Missing argument in parameter list"

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

What specific syntax needs to be changed in the `aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket bucketName --key fileName.tar.gz --tagging TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}` command to prevent the error shown below when the command is run in PowerShell?

Note that the `aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket bucketName --key fileName.tar.gz --tagging TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}` command syntax works perfectly when run in windows cmd on the very same computer.

Here is the PowerShell log including the command and the error message on the same computer where this command works in windows cmd:

```
PS C:\Users\userName> aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket bucketName --key fileName.tar.gz --tagging TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}
At line:1 char:129
+ ... --key fileName.tar.gz --tagging TagSet={Key=public,Value=ye ...
+                                                                 ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument

PS C:\Users\userName>
```

Also note that I am new to PowerShell.  I just sometimes now need to translate short scripts from other languages into PowerShell.

Comment: For options try one dash instead of two dashes.

Comment: @jdweng, the [`aws` CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/index.html) uses `--`, not `-` before parameter names.

Comment: To summarize: The only _shell syntax_ problem with the command in your question is that you cannot pass `TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}` _unquoted_ in PowerShell: -> `'TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}'`.
If that didn't help, the implication is that the `aws` command didn't work to begin with. Indeed, the shortcut syntax you're trying to use seems to require `[` and `]`: -> `'TagSet=[{Key=public,Value=yes}]'`
The fact that you managed to get _different_ `aws` syntax to work (a JSON string, the verbose alternative to the shorthand syntax) is not the answer to the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

*Update*:

- **The answer below addresses your question *as asked***, based on your (seemingly incorrect) claim that the first command mentioned in your question worked as-is from `cmd.exe`. **The points made below *generally* apply to the syntax of arguments passed to commands in PowerShell**.
- Based on a later comment, you state that what solved your problem was to pass a *JSON* string to the [`aws` CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/index.html)'s `--tagging` parameter:

  - You state that **`'{\"TagSet\": [{\"Key\":\"public\",\"Value\":\"yes\"}]}'`** worked for you (which represents the following *verbatim* JSON string: 
    `{"TagSet": [{"Key":"public","Value":"yes"}]`).

    - **Here too it is the *quoting* (`'...'`) that makes the argument work**, as discussed in the bottom section.
    - As an aside: This strange need to *manually* `\`-escape `"` characters embedded in an argument passed to external programs is indeed an - unfortunate - requirement in PowerShell up to at least v7.2.x, due to a *long-standing bug*. It *may* get fixed in a future version, which *may* require opt-in: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66837948/45375).
  - However, apart from the *PowerShell* syntax problem that is the subject of your question, it looks like **your original command simply used incorrect `aws` *shorthand* syntax** (a shorter alternative to passing JSON): according to the [docs for the `put-object-tagging` subcommand](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-tagging.html), the following should work - in addition to the required quoting (`'...'`) for PowerShell's sake, **note the `[...]`** around `{...}` which were missing from your own original command: 
    **`'TagSet=[{Key=public,Value=yes}]'`**

---

Replace:

```
TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}
```

with:

```bash
'TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}'
```

That is, ***quote* your argument**, which **prevents PowerShell from interpreting `{...}` as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)**, which is what caused your problem.

Note the use of a `'...'`, i.e a *single*-quoted [*verbatim* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings), which is the best choice if an argument contains *no* embedded variable references or subexpression (for the latter, you need *string interpolation* in the form of `"..."`, i.e., a *double*-quoted [*expandable* string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)).

PowerShell differs from other shells in two notable respects:

- its escape character is `` ` `` (the so-called *backtick*), not `\` (as in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash) or `^` (as in `cmd.exe`)
- it has *more* [metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) than other shells, such as `{`, `}`, and `@`

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375) for more information.

---

As for the **specific error message** you saw:

The content of a script block (`{ ... }`) is parsed as PowerShell code, and the content in your case, `Key=public,Value=yes`, is parsed as a command, whose syntax happens to be *invalid*:

- `Key=public` is interpreted as a *command name*
- `,Value=yes` is parsed as *its argument*, which - due to the `,` - is parsed *as an array*, but a literal array passed as an argument must not *start* with `,`, which is what the error message is trying to say: it's missing an array element *before* `,`
- You can more easily provoke this error by submitting the following on the command line:

  ```bash
  foo , bar # -> Error "Missing argument in parameter list."
  ```

Comment: The syntax that worked to solve the problem in the OP was actually the following instead: `aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket "myBucketName" --key "nameOfObject" --tagging '{\"TagSet\": [{\"Key\":\"public\",\"Value\":\"yes\"}]}'`