# git reset HEAD@{n} results in error "unknown switch 'e'"

Tags: git, powershell

I issued the command: git reset HEAD@{2} and got an error: unknown switch `e'.

What's happening?

Comment: Do you have an alias for git?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In PowerShell, unlike in `cmd.exe`, `@` and `{` / `}` are *metacharacters* that either require *individual* [escaping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) with `` ` `` (the so-called *backtick*) or *enclosing the entire argument in quotes*:

Therefore:

```bash
# Metacharacter-individual escaping
git reset HEAD`@`{2`} 

# Enclosing the whole argument in quotes
git reset 'HEAD@{2}'
```

Note:

- Strictly speaking , `@` is only a metacharacter at the *start* of an argument.
- The above uses a [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings); if string expansion (interpolation) is needed, use an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)
- For a list of *all* of PowerShell's metacharacters in [argument[-parsing] mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing#argument-mode), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66302956/45375).

---

As for the **obscure error message** you saw:

- Unescaped use of `{...}` causes the latter to be interpreted as a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks).
- Due to a *bug*, still present as of PowerShell 7.3.1, the presence of a script block inappropriately triggers translation of such an argument to a Base64-encoded argument passed to an `-encodedCommand` parameter, which is only meaningful when calling the PowerShell CLI ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+) - see [GitHub issue #10842](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10842).
- `git` therefore sees `-encodedCommand` on its command line, and complains about not knowing option `-e`.

Comment: Awesome answer, I already new the basic answer and was going to post it if no one else did, but this is so much better.

Comment: Ah; so `git` gets the `-encodedCommand` with a single hyphen and says "I don't do `-e`!" How esoteric.