# Powershell - Copying files with space and variables in the path

Tags: powershell

I have the script below, I am trying to use copy-item to copy two files. Unfortunately the file path include spaces in them, and I need to use variables to capture the correct files. I have used Test-Path to try and qualify the path, which seem to work, but in the script it is all failures.

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
$Yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

$folderdate = $Yesterday
$filedate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('dd.MM.yy')

Copy-Item -Path \\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\$Today\Daily MI $Yesterday'.xlsx' -Destination \\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\$folderdate\
Copy-Item -Path \\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\$Yesterday\$filedate' - West Brom MI.xls' -Destination \\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\$folderdate\
```

The file paths without the variables are below:

```
\\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\20230201\Daily MI 20230131.xlsx
\\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\20230131\31.01.23 - West Brom MI.xls
\\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\20230131\
```

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Wrap your paths with double quotes `"\\posa123......."`

Comment: For additional background information, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63983406/45375).

Comment: It is implied by Santiago's helpful answer, but to spell it out: use of `"..."` around the paths as a whole requires you to remove the `'` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your paths should be wrapped in a [expandable string `"..."`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#double-quoted-strings) otherwise each value between the spaces are interpreted and *bound* to other parameters, *considering there are available positional parameters available*. See [about Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters?view=powershell-7.2) for more details.

Take the following simple function to understand what's happening:

```
function Test {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string[]] $Path,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Destination,

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [object[]] $RemainingArgs
    )

    $PSBoundParameters
}
```

If we try the paths without quotes:

```
Test -Path \\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\$Today\Daily MI $Yesterday'.xlsx' -Destination \\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\$folderdate\
```

We can see that `MI` and `20230201.xlsx` are being bound to other, *remaining in this case*, parameters:

```
Key           Value
---           -----
Path          {\\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\20230202\Daily}
Destination   \\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\\
RemainingArgs {MI, 20230201.xlsx}
```

Instead, if we use quotes:

```
Test -Path "\\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\$Today\Daily MI $Yesterday.xlsx" -Destination "\\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\$folderdate\"
```

There shouldn't be any problem:

```
Key         Value
---         -----
Path        {\\posa1251\d$\File_Transfer\NBS\20230202\Daily MI 20230201.xlsx}
Destination \\wbbsmd.co.uk\corpdata\Corp\Group\NBS_WebSave_Reports\\
```